# Ajax Posting twice ASP NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(string mainFin, string actNumber, int actTypeId)
    {
  
        int userId = Int16.Parse(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));

        Act act = new Act()
        {
            ActTypeId = actTypeId,
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            ApproveDate = null,
            UserId = userId,
            StatusId = 1,
        };

        _unitOfWork.ActRepository.Add(act);
        _notyf.Success("Arayış əlavə edilid !");
        _unitOfWork.Complete();
        return RedirectToAction("Marriage");
    }
```

**AJAX**

```
$(function () {
var actTypeId = $("#questList option:selected").val();
console.log("QuestList ishledi !");
$('#formSubmit').click(function (e) {
    var mainFin = $("#FinInput").val();
    var actNumber = $("#actNumber").val();
    console.log(mainFin);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Index",
        type: "POST",
        data: { mainFin: mainFin, actNumber: actNumber },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("+++++");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("------");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#questForm1").submit();
});
});
```

Problem : When I click submit button data inserts twice to database (AJAX makes 2 request at same time )

Comment: is this `console.log(mainFin);` logged twice as well?

Comment: If you're submitting the data via AJAX, why are you also explicitly telling the form to submit?

Comment: No only insert query going twice

Comment: where is the actual error and issue taking place?

Comment: @SimonPrice They described the insert is taking place twice. Did you need more clarification about that? Which part do you need clarification on?

Comment: and are you getting a double logging in the conole?

Comment: @SimonPrice They already answered that question. Please read prior comments before posting your own.

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting your data twice: at first using ajax and after that using using the form submit.

You have to remove one of them, I would guess the form submit.
Also, since ajax is called async, if you want to do something after ajax has been called and returned successfully, you have to put the code in success section.

So the code should look like:

```
$(function () {
var actTypeId = $("#questList option:selected").val();
console.log("QuestList ishledi !");
$('#formSubmit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

    var mainFin = $("#FinInput").val();
    var actNumber = $("#actNumber").val();
    console.log(mainFin);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Index",
        type: "POST",
        data: { mainFin: mainFin, actNumber: actNumber },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("+++++");
            // do your thing here, once the ajax requst has returned successfully
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("------");
        }
    });
  
    // NOTICE: form submit removed
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit the form via AJAX then you need to remove the last line of the click event handler.

`$("#questForm1").submit();`

This line is submitting the form and essentially negating the `e.preventDefault()` above.